# Unable to find the nth child or nth of type of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Every time I try to select the nth of type of a class or the nth child either in the chrome console or through CSS selectors in selenium, I always get back a result of length 0. I will provide some of the HTML below. If anyone has any idea why this is happening or an alternative way to do this would be greatly appreaciated.

`<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Yes</span></button>`

So when typing onto the console

`$('.ui-dialog-buttonset.dialogbtn_cntr:nth-of-type(3)')`

or

`$('.ui-dialog-buttonset.dialogbtn_cntr:nth-child(3)')`

I have also tried 
I have tried the

`$('.ui-dialog-buttonset.dialogbtn_cntr:eq(3)')`

the returned result is

````
length: 0
prevObject: init [document, context: document]
context: document
selector: ".ui-dialog-buttonset.dialogbtn_cntr:nth-child(3)"
__proto__: Object(0)```
````

Comment: are you sure you have an element `.ui-dialog-buttonset.dialogbtn_cntr` which is the third element of a given type (or the third child) related to a common parent? Please provide a minimal example showing the issue

Comment: We kind of really need your HTML code to see if your selector is doing what you want

Comment: HTML code is too long to post, which is why i provided the snippet :) yeah I am sure there is a third element of that given type, there are 4 elements they go 0 1 2 3 and I want to be able to select any of them! Just doesn't work sadly.

Comment: There is NO CSS selector that will select `nth-of-class`...that might be the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you know any other way of fetching that element? The problem is that the HTML was written poorly!

Comment: Without sight of the HTML it's impossible to answer.